# How to have vscode syntax highlight for django template tag in js

Tags: javascript, django, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to have a proper django syntax highlight in vscode when using django template tag in a  tag in templates ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like [@HotTeaPot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14857220/hotteapot) said, I would recommend [`vscode-django`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=batisteo.vscode-django) extension by Baptiste Darthenay for syntax highlighting and snippets along with `djlint` for formatting.

You can ignore errors through a .djlintrc file.

```json
// .djlintrc

{
    "ignore": "T002,H020,H031,H030"
}
```

Include the snippet below in your USER settings.json to extend html emmet-completions in django-html.

```json
// settings.json

  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "django-html": "html",
    "jinja-html": "html"
  },
```

Happy coding!!!

Answer (score 1):

Well, i would say just download the Django extension from Baptiste Darthenay. From what I've seen it and what I've understand it's what you are looking for.